# Why won't my Activity start?

Tags: android

I have an industrial app which is remotely controlled from a PC.  The app has 2 slightly different versions - one for a Honeycomb tablet and the other for a Gingerbread phone.   The differences are to take advantage of unique features in the hardware (e.g., the phone has a better camera, the tablet can display bigger graphics) but the Activity-starting code is the same.

A thread in the app receives commands from the PC and displays different screens (i.e., starts different Activities).    It works fine on the phone but on the tablet one activity won't start, but throws no exceptions.  Breakpoints and logging in that activity's *onResume()* are never hit, even though they are on the phone.   Here's how I try to start the activity . . .

```
    try {
        Intent svc = new Intent(ctx, RemoteControlActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(svc);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {  // or ActivityNotFoundException e
        Log.d("ShowButtons(normal)", "startActivity failed");
    }
```

(ctx is a Context -  in the debugger the Context is the same for both the working on non-working cases)

The activity which is failing to start on the tablet is defined like this in the manifest . . .

```
   <activity
       android:launchMode="singleTask"   
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:windowNoTitle="false"
       android:configChanges="orientation"
       android:screenOrientation="landscape"
       android:name="RemoteControlActivity">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is driving me batty -  thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: No error trace and no exception when executing `ctx.startActivity`?

Comment: isnt a '.' required before   RemoteControlActivity in the android:name ?

Comment: @fiddler -  correct -  it throws no exceptions (as I said in the OP)

Comment: @G_S -  there's no "." in the working case, i.e., on the phone version.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but the activity that's failing to start is the main activity for the app, so it was already started once when the app first started.   Essentially, I'm really trying to "REStart" it.    And again, this works perfectly on the phone.  Is there a Honeycomb / Gingerbread issue I need to know about?

Comment: check what you are getting in the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.   I'm posting it this way so I can mark it as "answered" incase anyone else runs into this and is searching for a workaround.  But I admit I don't understand why it works.

The breakthrough was discovering that it mattered what activity was currently on the screen when I was trying to start RemoteControlActivity.    The failure was happening when I had an activity that displayed some graphics on the screen.   I substituted a different activity that displayed some buttons and the problem went away.

Looking at the Manifest I noticed that the "good" activity was set to:

```
Android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

and the "bad" one was set to:

```
Android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

When I changed the graphics activity to "singleTask" the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Intent svc = new Intent(ctx, RemoteControlActivity.class);
   svc.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   ctx.startActivity(svc);
```

According to the docs

> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in

Comment: I really thought this would work; I was already preparing a thank-you note, but alas, no luck.    The Activity still doesn't start (at least onResume never gets hit) but no exceptions are thrown.   This is baffling.

Comment: could you post your onCreate() of your RemoteControlActivity, and which API level is it?? I am really curious now why your activity is not starting.

Comment: API level is 13.  The onCreate is huge and contains proprietary content and as I said, since it's the main activity it's already been started successfully once.    However I do have a new clue . . .                                                                The critical factor seems to be what Activity is currently on top.  The activity currently running when it's failing to start is one that displays some JPEG graphics and some buttons.    If I substitute a different activity, e.g., one that displays a grid of buttons, the RemoteControlActivity starts up just fine.